# DateTimePicker not recognized in my app

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to figure this out for days but nothing has come of it.

I want to have a date time picker on my cshtml page but it keeps coming up with the following:

**JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datetimepicker'**

I thought I had the proper links on my page but obviously not.

Have tried so many times with different combinations but no joy.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datetimepicker.css" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>

<script>
    $('#DateOfAppointment').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
    });
</script>
```

The link I am trying to use: https://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Clean-jQuery-Date-Time-Picker-Plugin-datetimepicker.html

Comment: execute datetimepicker function on document ready.

Comment: I think you copy/paste the code and you didn't realize this asset `jquery.datetimepicker.js` is not in your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the assets you're using, check the code below and download the js file and css file in order to get it work in your project.

```js
$('#DateOfAppointment').datetimepicker({
  inline: true,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://xdsoft.net/cache/903cd11f82fad90c9e8c4c45801eb6f2.js"></script>

<script src="https://xdsoft.net/scripts/datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://xdsoft.net/scripts/datetimepicker/build/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<input type="text" id="DateOfAppointment" />
```

**Hope it helps!**

Answer (score 0):

On document ready will solve your problem

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#DateOfAppointment').datetimepicker({
        inline: true,
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem unfortunately, I get the following **JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'datetimepicker'**

Comment: then please check whether files are included properly or not.